# How would I fix a SKView if it returns nil?

Tags: swift, uiview, sprite-kit, skscene

i have a class that holds this function

```
func valueChanged() {
    run(tapSound)
    let sceneto = scenes[segment.selectedSegmentIndex]
    let trans = SKTransition.fade(with: .white, duration: 1.5)
    if view == nil {
        print("view is nil")
    } else {
        view?.presentScene(sceneto, transition: trans)
        print("ran",segment.selectedSegmentIndex,scenes.count)
    }
}
```

Each scene I am trying to transition to inherits from this class, so they all have this function. However this function runs fine once, and the scene changes, but after the first time, view keeps returning nil and I don't understand why. The function is located in the class that each scene inherits if that makes any difference

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to go on. Is `view` declared in the same class as this function? Is there a single `SKView` instance that is supposed to be shared between these classes? How is `view` supposed to be set?

Comment: the view is don't by a separate view class, so this class shouldn't remove the view at all, view is set when the app loads.

Comment: I think that your problem is not in this bit of code but is to do with the `view` variable, where and how it is declared and how it is set.

Comment: If a view is nil, means that scene is not presented yet. For example, in scene's init, it is normal that its view property is nil.

Comment: @ChrisHutchison Is the segmented control wired up to a view controller via an @IBOutlet? That will have to call your `valueChanged` function in an instance of your class (you're not calling it as a class method) so how is that call handled? It would be very useful to see the code for the view controller.

Comment: no, the segmented control is added programmatically

Comment: @ChrisHutchison If you have multiple scene, you have multiple copies of `valueChanged`. How to you know which copy of this function is getting called when the segmented Control is changed? If the copy being called is not in the currently presented scene, then that's your problem. Is it the scene that adds the segmentedControl or some other view controller? Can you show us the code that adds the segmentControl and which class that code is in?

Comment: The issue is that the instance of this scene is no longer on the SKView, that is why you are getting nil.  So either a scene died but did not deinit, or you are calling this before the scene is added to the SKView

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so how would I go about correcting that?

Comment: @ChrisHutchison I suspect when you add your segmentedControl, you wire it up to call 'valueChanged' *in a specific scene*, rather than the currently presented scene. Initially the scene whose `valueChanged` function is called when the segmentedControl is changed *is* the currently presented scene, but after the transition to the new scene, it no longer is and that's your problem. You will need to ensure that the `valueChanged` function called is the one in the presented scene, and not the one in the initial scene.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more information for me to correctly diagnose it, but from the looks of it you are dealing with your SKScene [ARC (Automatic Reference Count)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48) is reaching zero which allows it to be deallocated.

Basically, the application will hold onto a class as long as someone is still using it. When you create a class instance its ARC is set to 1. When you save that instance somewhere else, it goes up to 2. When those are set to nil the ARC drops by one each time. When it hits zero, it is not being used anywhere and can and will be deallocated.

It is possible that your array is using `weak` variables to the SKScene instances. The difference between `weak` and `strong` variables is that the former does not add one to the ARC while the latter does. If `scenes[segment.selectedSegmentIndex]` references a weak variable, then it will either be a SKScene as defined or nil, depending on whether or not it has been deallocated.

What is most likely is the the `scenes[]` variable is referencing a specific scene's instance, but when that scene is over and dismissed, it sets that instance to nil.

Something to keep in mind is that you may not want to hold onto a specific instance of SKScene, otherwise you will use up unnecessary memory and load a scene that has already been played out.

It would be better to hold the class type in the array and recreate the scene before the transition.